# Product of all multinomial coefficients

Tags: asymptotics, multinomial-coefficients

At some moment I found that for computing a bound on a density, I need to compute (or find a good asymptotic) of the product of all multinomial coefficients, i.e.,
$$
\prod_{\substack{(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^k\\\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i=n}}\binom{n}{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k}.
$$
For the binomial coefficients, I found that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}=\sqrt{e}.
$$
However, I didn't found anything regarding generalizations of the above formula for multinomial coefficients. Before starting to manipulate expressions after writing plenty of Stirling's approximations, I want to ask: does there exist any similar formula for the product of all multinomial coefficients?

Comment: I think there must be a typo in the first formula: $n$ and $\alpha_n$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Dieter Kadelka Yes, you are right! Changed it by $k$

Comment: Does the order of $\alpha_i$'s matter?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov Yes, the idea is that you have to multiply all multinomial coefficients appearing the multinomial expansion

Comment: Sorry for a mistake before, the product of multinomial coefficients probably is $\frac{(n!)^{\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}}}{\left(\prod_{a=0}^{k} (a!)^{\binom{n-a+k-2}{k-2}}\right)^k}$, for $k \leq n$

Comment: If anyone is amusing themselves by computing this, be warned that convergence appears slow (e.g., for n=10,000, k=2, the result differs in the 4th significant digit from the limit, at least with my code.)

Comment: The product in the denominator is from $a=0$ to $n$ , not $k$. That's a typo, sorry. And simplifying the previous identity we get, $$\prod_{a=1}^{n} a^{\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}-k\binom{n+k-a-1}{k-1}}$$.